# (FRIDA) Failed to spawn: unable to access zygote64 while preparing for app launch; try disabling Magisk Hide in case it is active

Tags: android, frida

Im running Frida Server (frida-server-12.5.8-android-arm64.xz) in Android 8 (Oreo) as **root**:

-rwxrwxrwx 1 root  root  38152536 2019-05-26 23:34 irwan

```
./irwan &
```

and then I try this to unpinning ssl in apk :

```
C:\Users\irwan>frida -U -f xxx.xxxxx -l "C:\Users\irwan\OneDrive\pentest\payload\frida\unpinning_universal.js"
```

the output error :

> Failed to spawn: unable to access zygote64 while preparing for app
>   launch; try disabling Magisk Hide in case it is active

as the following the picture:

[the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpXnF.png)

- Frida 12.5.8
- Python 3.7.3
- Windows 10 Pro

can someone help me to implement or create step by step solutions for this problem? thanks.

Comment: Do you use root via Magisk? Is there an Magisk anti-root detection module active as the error message suggests?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, is rooting phones without magisk an option nowadays? I don't know how to go ahead at this point

Answer (score 9):

<s>https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:ouBQw77t4r8J:https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/905+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk</s> (Cache was also unavaliable,but the content was the same as following steps.)

Just disable Magisk Hide to fix this :

Magisk Manager > Settings >Magisk > Magisk Hide (Toggle Off)

Comment: cache  also unaccessible

Comment: For people wondering why this is needed, Magisk Hide ptraces the zygote module in order to intercept calls, which locks out other apps from doing so, and zygote is needed by Frida to spawn apps and do early hooking.

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @gmlime,

Frida and Magisk require Zygote module to spawn processes.
Magisk Hide ptraces the zygote module in order to intercept calls, which locks out other apps from doing so, and zygote is needed by Frida to spawn apps and do early hooking.

We can temporarily disable MagiskHide. We can quickly disable it through the command-line using adb.
Run

```
adb shell "su -c magiskhide disable"
```

And then recheck with your frida command, It should work.